# Don't understand why theming is so strange and twisted

Tags: theme-development, code

What I'm asking you here is not a technical question, but more a philosophical one. I firstly started developing themes for a small new cms that I also contributed on github that has a great potential, its name is anchor-cms.

Now I'm developing themes for wordpress and I noticed how bad it is in front of anchor when we're talking about themes development. I could bring you plenty of examples to prove what I'm saying. Let's start with the "comment form" function: why the developer who's creating a theme must be forced to use the wordpress markup?
Another example is when you have to retrieve the comments of a post... just incredible the way I'm forced to get those data, with all that bloated markup and also when you have to get the thumbnail of a post and Wordpress instead of giving you the url of that image, returns with a whole img tag to use.
The funny comes when you have to adapt that markup to your needs and you have to pass configuration parameters (like arrays) to the functions. I see these things like a patch on a patch on a patch and honestly these are things that lead the developers to be incredibly constrained to the "rules".

I think that Wordpress is bloated and it's meant to bloat. I don't know if it's just me and my obsession about writing beautiful code, neat, simple, and fast as hell but developing on WP takes me to write a lot of extra stuff in my code that make everything heavier and I noticed on the web that I'm not the only one that thinks this.
I hope you understood the ideas I wanted to express with my poor english.

Comment: I'm not really disagreeing with you, in total at least, but as this is bound to be going nowhere productive, I have close voted at »primarily opinion-based«.

Comment: You should open a discussion on trac and discuss this with the core developers. We can't do anythingabout this issues :-)

Comment: Well it's ok to me, but I don't think is necessary to contact the developers. Could you tell me where can I ask a similar question to discuss this thought?

Comment: @PieterGoosen If it was you, or to whoever it was, I would say there is no good reason to put an extra down vote in - just saying.

Comment: @ialocin agreed, it would be a great discussion, but really, ......

Comment: @pieterGoosen You know I thought stackexchange wasn't absolutely the right place to write this thing, but actually I wanted to see if I was the only one to think this and I don't know any other places to talk about this stuff... so...

Comment: @PieterGoosen Totally, but this isn't the place. Giacomo, there are some G+ groups which might be better suited, but I'm not that familiar with them.

Comment: @ialocin me neither, anyway sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: It isn't a big problem, so don't mention it. Besides it is a somewhat interesting topic, just not suitable for [wordpress.se], because of its guidelines, if you are interested give the [help] a read.

Comment: @PieterGoosen Opinions can differ, but looking at your voting stats I personally would say level your voting behavior :) But as said opinions - and behavior - differ.

Comment: This should be an interesting discussion indeed. I would just add that some talented persons left the WordPress ecosystem due to its drawbacks. Not to mention that PHP tends to be a low entry barrier which explains a lot of early decisions in WordPress's architecture.

Comment: @ialocin I really appreciate your concerns and suggestions, and I do take it to heart, but such quarells should really be discussed and sorted on [meta], and I'm really open to take it there. Let we not soil our differences here. :-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen I feel like you are right, if this matter should be discussed broader, then it should happen on [meta]. But on the other hand, I just made a remark, a little one, nothing more really, on an observation about this specific case, so I don't think it is totally wrong to do it here. Besides, as stated, I accept the differences, I just just think a bit different about it - nothing more. In short, if you are going to open up a general, after all it is not really about you specifically at the end, discussion, then I might join. But in a way it is a can of worms I'm not willing to open.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I'm developing themes for wordpress and I noticed how bad it is in front of anchor when we're talking about themes development. I could bring you plenty of examples to prove what I'm saying. Let's start with the "comment form" function: why the developer who's creating a theme must be forced to use the wordpress markup?

You aren't, WordPress provides default markup, but you don't have to use it. The input var names on the other hand are necessary for obvious reasons else the form won't work, and a lot of the markup you dislike is merely the default value of several options you can pass into the comment form function being called.

I put this down to a lack of knowledge

> Another example is when you have to retrieve the comments of a post... just incredible the way I'm forced to get those data, with all that bloated markup

There's more than one way to do things, you could have total control if you did it this way:

```
$args = array(
   // args here
);

// The Query
$comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
$comments = $comments_query->query( $args );

// Comment Loop
if ( $comments ) {
    foreach ( $comments as $comment ) {
        echo '<p>' . $comment->comment_content . '</p>';
    }
} else {
    echo 'No comments found.';
}
```

Not every API is low level, some are higher level functions for people who aren't strong developers, or to save time with defaults, some are there for historic reasons and backwards compatability, etc

> and also when you have to get the thumbnail of a post and Wordpress instead of giving you the url of that image, returns with a whole img tag to use.

No, there is a function that does this, `the_post_thumbnail`, but perhaps you would get better results using `get_post_thumbnail_id` to find the post ID of the attachment that represents the thumbnail, and `wp_get_attachment_url`:

```
$featured_image = get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_id() );
$url = wp_get_attachment_url( $featured_image );
echo '<img src="'.$url.'"/>
```

> The funny comes when you have to adapt that markup to your needs and you have to pass configuration parameters (like arrays) to the functions. I see these things like a patch on a patch on a patch and honestly these are things that lead the developers to be incredibly constrained to the "rules".

Perhaps you should use a lower level API, some of the higher level APIs that do a lot of things, and don't require basic knowledge of how data is stored do have a lot of parameters for things like markup, e.g. `wp_list_categories`, etc, it sounds like you'd be better off using the lower level APIs such as the term/taxonomy classes/functions

All the things you're suggesting WordPress do, already exist. There's no 1 single way to do something in WordPress, each way is optimal for a different level of knowledge and use case.

Comment: "[...] no 1 single way to do something in WordPress" this is one of its biggest issues in my opinion and a lot of confusion stems from this fact.

Comment: @tom j nowell You're right when you say that there is no 1 single way to do something in wordpress and that's the problem. Things must be built with semplicity in mind. So I don't have to work with a lower level API, but I would like to have functions that give the necessary and not more.And a lack of knowledge? Man, you have to use the wordpress markup for the submit button and don't tell me that's not true, and there are other 2 input tags hidden to pass parameters to wordpress.I said, I contributed to anchor, and ABSOLUTELY there are no such things.

Comment: Anchor is a super lightweight CMS with different goals, history, and functionality to WordPress. That you contributed to it, or that it's mentioned is entirely irrelevant. You may hold a different opinion, but this is stack exchange, a Q&A site, not a forum. We deal with facts, and your question can't be answered in a concrete absolute fashion, so it was closed